# Predicting health of power supplies

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc, testing

I have a couple of 12 V, 1200 mA [wall mount power supplies](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/410/WDU12-1200-1351018.pdf).

[image]

Currently, using a digital multi-meter, I am able to measure good voltage and amps coming out of some power supplies.

Since these are getting older, is there a way to do a preventive test to figure out if some will "die" the next time they are used? I have other ones that have failed upon use.

Comment: Why do you need to predict the failure exactly? Because you need an uninterrupted power supply? Or because you need time in advance to buy a replacement? Did your failed power supplies fail always in the same application/same context (e.g. always when connected to some specific load)?

Comment: BTW, I edited your question to link directly to the datasheet and inserted a relevant datasheet excerpt in the question. Keep in mind for your future posts: links may rot and at least a minimum of data from the links should be embedded in the post itself if the data is central to understanding your question or putting it in the right context.

Comment: If you're worried about the failure of 12v wallwarts, buy some spares and keep them on hand.  Failure will probably be total, so you'll know easily enough.

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't tell if it's about to die.

If you are measuring the "good amps" by short-circuiting the output with the meter's ammeter you may hasten the death of both the power supply and the meter.

You could test the power supply by connecting it to a load designed to draw the rated power from the power supply and monitoring the voltage to ensure that it stays within specification. This should probably be done over an hour or so to ensure temperature stability.

An inspection may reveal some swolen electrolytic capacitors or parts showning scorching indicating that they are running at high temperatures and more likely to fail.

Answer (score 7):

To test power supplies you need a suitable load sized to draw full current (and no more) at the rated output voltage.

If you're testing them with a "load" that's just the shunt resistor of an ammeter, to measure the "amps", you may soon experience the joy of paying for a new HRC fuse. They are not super cheap. And you're overloading those poor supplies! They are not meant to drive ≈1Ω loads (that's a low cost multimeter shunt in series with low cost probes).

A 12V, 1.2A supply needs the following load resistor ratings:
$$
R = U/I = 12{\rm\,V}/1.2{\rm\,A}=10\,\Omega, \\
P = U\cdot I = 12{\rm\,V}\cdot 1.2{\rm\,A}=14.4{\rm\,W}.
$$

You need to load the supply with a 10Ω 15W resistor and only *then* measure:

- the current flowing through the resistor,
- the DC voltage on the resistor,
- the AC ripple on the resistor.

As for predicting their health: it may be possible, but is much more complicated than just testing them with a load and seeing whether they work or not. It becomes a rather serious experimental design problem.

The best one can do without going overboard is ensure two things:

1. That no supplies have excessive AC ripple, since that's a sign of failing smoothing capacitors. Check ripple under load on all supplies, and treat high-side outliers as likely to fail soon.
2. Leave the power supply under load for a couple of hours. If it still meets specs in terms of voltage, current and ripple after that time has elapsed, the probability of near-term failure is quite low.

Ensure the load resistor is mounted on a good heatsink, e.g. a junk CPU cooler from a PC, with the fan running. *The load rating of a resistor is usually at a certain temperature, and that temperature becomes fiction without heatsinking*.

**Do not under any circumstances leave the test setup unattended, due to fire risk.**

Comment: Given the [schematic](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/410/WDU12-1200-1351018.pdf) (plain transformer+bridge+capacitor), indeed the AC ripple under load is a good indicator of capacitor reaching EOL (it will also be quite high for a broken diode). Other failures will have the DC voltage much too low (typically 0).

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps make a statistical estimate on life left by measuring the output AC ripple for a given load as the output capacitor is likely the first thing to fail.

Something like this should do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDumVp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

High AC voltage reading on V_AC multimeter = bad capacitor = bad power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, without disassembling and examining a power supply (generally destructively), there's often no good way of predicting failure modes, or what warning signs would be exhibited first.  Some linear power supplies for Commodore computers are notorious for having an internal connection work loose in a manner that causes them to output excessive voltage, to the extreme detriment of whatever is plugged into them.  Other power supplies may have capacitors that degrade causing an increase in ripple voltage or excessive leakage that causes excessive mains power draw and heating.

Since this does not appear to be a regulated supply, it does not seem likely to fail in a manner that would cause a harmful over-voltage condition.  If open-circuit ripple voltage is significant, that would indicate that the cap is likely generating heat and may at some point explode, spewing gunk inside the supply with unknown effects.  Otherwise, the supply may keep working for decades with a gradual degradation in the voltage during the lowest part of the ripple when loaded, and "failure" being defined as the point where the device being supplied cannot tolerate the voltage sag.  If the open-circuit ripple remains small, one could predict failure by monitoring the low points in the output waveform and seeing when they start to approach the minimum voltage required for reliable operation of the device being powered.